# Unity Android TouchscreenKeyboard does not appear

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm making an android application using unity3d.

The keyboard is being used to enter a Name for a digital Pet.

The code I am using can be seen below, it is triggered by the user pressing a button in a menu screen.

```
TouchScreenKeyboard keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("Franklin");

if (keyboard != null)
    SetPetName(keyboard.text);
```

Once the button has been pressed the Pet's name has been changed to 'Franklin' but no keyboard appear on screen.

I can't see where I am going wrong here, and I have not been able to find any similar issues posted.
One thought I had was that it may be in some way related to the fact I am locking the screen orientation to horizontal, but this is something i need to do on my application.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: Have you try your app on device? It seems `TouchScreenKeyboard.Open` does not work in Editor.

Comment: Oh thanks, i will try building it to my phone, i have only been using the editor with 'unity remote' so far.

Comment: Thanks man that was it, i would have though that using unity remote it would still work but never mind. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment above solves this issue. It was that TouchScreenKeyboard.Open doesn't work in the editor. Once built to my device it was all OK.